# Node server response is HTML after adding catch-all to allow react-router to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have been developing a node backend, react front end web app for a couple months. It has working just fine when I started the server via nodemon and the front end with npm start. But now that I am getting ready to host an alpha version and ran 'npm run build' I've been running into issues.

It seems to be stemming from the interaction of accessing the app from the server's port and react-router. I added a catch-all endpoint app.get('/*'...) to my server to allow the react-router to work. So now when the front requests data, the response is HTML not the array I want.

I feel like there is a simple solution to this, but I just don't see it yet. I looked into using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter, but unfortunately I can't use that because I am using MSAL Active Directory for login.

server/index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
require('dotenv').config();
const massive = require('massive');
const session = require("express-session");
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const ctrl = require(`./controllers/controller.js`);

//Middleware
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + './../build'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Connection to Azure DB
massive(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING)
.then(db => {
    console.log('Connected to Azure PostgreSQL Database')
    app.set('db', db)
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, 
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
   })); 
 
//Endpoints
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './../build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
  })

app.get('/getallemployees/', ctrl.getAllEmployees)

app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Listening on ${8080}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that catch-all endpoint after all the others that return data.

```js
//Endpoints
app.get('/getallemployees/', ctrl.getAllEmployees)

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './../build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Now I feel dumb. Thanks!